# Is it possible to run ROS Indigo and Kinetic Kame on multiple machines together?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a PC (Ubuntu 14) and nVidia Jetson TX1 (Ubuntu 16) and I know that Ubuntu 14 can run ROS Indigo and the Ubuntu 16 can run ROS Kinetic Kame.
Of course I can install Ubuntu 16 on the PC but I have some comparability problems with my applications on Ubuntu 16.
So I want to run ROS Indigo and Kinetic Kame together in distributed mode.
Is it possible to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261446/is-it-possible-to-run-ros-indigo-and-kinetic-kame-on-multiple-machines-together?/) by [NickVot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30327/nickvot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked a couple of times before, copying an earlier answer from #q252118.

Although it is not advisable, mixing ROS versions will work in some cases. Naturally, it depends on which versions you are trying to mix, but for at least a number of the newest releases, the underlying communication protocol hasn't changed, so as long as your message definitions are identical, it should work. Obviously, if the message definition changes for the newer distro, this will no longer work so there's no saying if it will continue to work.

For a more elaborate explanation, take a look at the following related questions: #q104086, #q76279 and #q37403.

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0